# Oracle SQL Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I have 2 tables in my Database:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create a Query that should take in as a variable parameter "**id3**" so for example -

**Q(z0)** should produce

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle queries can take parameter in 2 forms one is ANSI sql binding [inform of ?] and other is Oracle Style binding [in form of :1].

So your query can be :

```
    Select * from table1 a, table2 b where a.id1 = b.id1 
and a.id2 = b.id2 and id3 = :1
```

Comment: You will get the every row of table2 repeated for each row that matched table1. You need some JOIN predicates!

Comment: @JamesAnderson: Agreed. My aim was just to show how to pass param. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 I
         JOIN TAB2 II ON I.id1 = II.id1 and I.id2 = II.id2
WHERE I.id3 = 'z0'
```

Should produce the result you require, you may need a "LEFT OUTER JOIN " if TAB2 is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming the 'A','B','C' are known the query is

```
    With extra_cols as(
                    SELECT * FROM (
                                    SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = (
                                                                      SELECT id1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE id3 = 'z0'
                                                                      ) 
                                                          AND  id2 = (
                                                                      SELECT id2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE id3 = 'z0'
                                                                      )
                                  )
                  PIVOT (STR(VALUE_1) for FIXED_COL in ('A','B','C')) 
                )
SELECT * from table1 left join extra_cols on table1.id1 = extra_cols.id1 AND table1.id2 = extra_cols.id2
WHERE TABLE1.id3 = 'z0'
```

The 'A' , 'B' , 'C' String can be extracted from

```
SELECT FIXED_COL AS Names FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.id1=(SELECT id1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE id3 = 'z0') AND Table2.id2=(SELECT id2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE id3 = 'z0')
```